# In SQL Server what's the difference between SESSIONPROPERTY and @@Options?

Tags: .net, sql-server

In my .Net application, if I execute the following, the values don't match:

```
SELECT 
    SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT'), 
    CASE WHEN (@@OPTIONS & 64) = 64 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I was under the impression that `SESSIONPROPERTY` and `@@OPTIONS` would generate the same results. In my case, `SESSIONPROPERTY` is returning 0 and `@@OPTIONS` is returning 1.

Which is more accurate, and why?

Comment: According to the documentation they *should* be the same [Configure the user options Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-options-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017#Recommendations). I feel like we're  missing a piece of the puzzle here.

Comment: What version of .NET and SQL Server?

Comment: .Net 4.7.1 & SQL Server 2014

Comment: And to be super clear, I had modified the database's default setting for ARITHABORT using:
    ALTER DATABASE [theDb] SET ARITHABORT ON WITH NO_WAIT
Then, I launched my .Net app and observed the confusion that I mention in the Question.

Comment: Might want to test some of the other SETs to see if there's a consistent pattern. To me, the doc is a little squirrely about what precisely scopes the values of either thing. Further, it could be that SqlConnection does some SET defaults that exacerbate those differences.

Comment: I repro'd in Sql Server 2016/SP1 & .Net 4.5, fwiw. Looks like @@options isn't correctly reflecting the alter database. The behavior persists through a restart of the server.

Comment: This is not .NET specific. `sqlcmd -S . -d Foo -Q "SELECT CAST(SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT') AS INT), CASE WHEN (@@OPTIONS & 64) = 64 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"` will repro it (and even `osql`): `SESSIONPROPERTY` will return the DB default, while `@@OPTIONS` returns the actual active setting. Performing an explicit `SET ARITHABORT` (`ON` or `OFF` both) brings the values in line. For both .NET and `sqlcmd`, the connecting clients actually set `ARITHABORT` to `OFF` by passing it as such in the login packet, which is the expected behavior (modern clients do not leave this up to the DB defaults).

Comment: To further complicate matters (possibly): because clients also by default set `ANSI_WARNINGS` to `ON`, the *actual* effect will be as if `ARITHABORT` is active anyway; to have `ARITHABORT` actually do nothing on an arithmetic error `ANSI_WARNINGS` has to be `OFF` as well.

Comment: A much better question is what you *think* setting the DB default will achieve. The correct answer is "absolutely nothing for any modern client". You wouldn't have even noticed this if things had been left to the defaults -- the weird behavior of `SESSIONPROPERTY` notwithstanding.

Comment: @jeroen-mostert, you're correct about using `ANSI_WARNINGS=ON` and `ARITHABORT=OFF` will have the effect of `ARITHABORT=ON`.  However, there's a side-effect on execution plans.  If `ARITHABORT` is `ON` in SSMS (which is the default) and it's `OFF` in .Net (which is the default), the two clients will be using different execution plans (regardless of `ANSI_WARNINGS`).  I was attempting to find some way to turn it on in .Net without invoking a separate round-trip for every connection.  I didn't think the database default would work, but I figured I'd try.  And then, I noticed the madness.

Comment: Yes, the dreaded "why is my query slow here but not there" phenomenon -- this can be a nuisance, but if it really bothers you the better workaround is probably to reconfigure SSMS (since you can't reconfigure ADO.NET). [See this writeup on the matter](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#defaultsettings). Of course, you'd have to do that everywhere SSMS is used -- I tend not to bother and just keep this problem in mind for when it rears its ugly head, since hoping to change every SSMS config for every dev everywhere isn't in the cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jeroen...it's not .Net specific. The `@@OPTIONS` are reflecting what comes in on the connection, while `SESSIONPROPERTY` does not. Open a trace to see what's happening on the connection, and you'll see what a .Net default connection does:

[image]

I've done the same set ahead of running the commands:

```
alter database [thedatabase] set arithabort on with no_wait
```

...and my test harness is:

```
using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=thedatabase;Integrated Security=True" ) )
{
  conn.Open( );
  using ( var cmd = conn.CreateCommand( ) )
  {
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SESSIONPROPERTY( 'ARITHABORT' ), CASE WHEN(@@OPTIONS &64) = 64 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    using ( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader( ) )
    {
      while ( reader.Read( ) )
      {
        Console.WriteLine( "{0},{1}", reader[ 0 ], reader[ 1 ] );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One wonders if it's a bug...or just squirrely doc.

Comment: My money is on "bug", because, if you add a `SET ARITHABORT OFF/ON;` before the `SELECT`, the values will match. There is no conceivable reason (well, no *good* one) why the option bits passed in the login handshake should be treated differently from the options as they're explicitly `SET`. That said, there's a slight chance it's not a complete bug but a compatibility misfeature (it's the sort of thing you could imagine some ancient business critical application from 20 years ago to break on were it to change).

Comment: Good point on the "compatibility misfeature". Either way, it's too bad that `SESSIONPROPERTY` is the interface that's gakked up. It's consistent in form with APIs like `OBJECTPROPERTY` and `COLUMNPROPERTY`. The `@@OPTIONS` interface, while seemingly reasonable to old geeks like me, strikes me as an archaic interface. If I ever cared about the state of a SET, I believe I'd have preferred `SESSIONPROPERTY`.

Comment: I accept this answer because it explains that @@Options is "more accurate," and it demonstrates why.  I'd love to have the underlying reason explained - but that's way beyond the scope of my question.  And I agree that it's probably some old code that nobody's touched in 20 years.